# How to set up a legend with Graphview in Android Studio

Tags: android, legend, android-graphview

I have a screen on my app that display the following graph:

[image]

Is there a way to change my legend so that it can say what each color represents? Currently I can get the blue square to show up but it doesn't represent any of the numbers. Here is the code I'm using when creating the graph:

```
GraphView graph = (GraphView) findViewById(R.id.graph);

        BarGraphSeries<DataPoint> series = new BarGraphSeries<DataPoint>(new DataPoint[]{
                new DataPoint(1, personal),
                new DataPoint(2, fun),
                new DataPoint(3, work),
                new DataPoint(4, food),
                new DataPoint(5, commute),
                new DataPoint(6,bills)
        });


        graph.setTitle("Expenses");
        graph.addSeries(series);
        graph.getLegendRenderer().setVisible(true);
        graph.getLegendRenderer().setAlign(LegendRenderer.LegendAlign.TOP);
        series.setValueDependentColor(new ValueDependentColor<DataPoint>() {
            @Override
            public int get(DataPoint data) {
                return Color.rgb((int) data.getX() * 255 / 4, (int) Math.abs(data.getY() * 255 / 6), 100);
            }
        });
        series.setSpacing(50);

        series.setDrawValuesOnTop(true);
        series.setValuesOnTopColor(Color.RED);

        backToMainMenu();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you need to customize the legend. The LegendRenderer class uses the title of each series of data to display what the bars on the chart represent.

```
series.setTitle("This will display in the legend.");
```

However, you only have one series of data in this example. If you must have labels in the legend for each bar, I suggest adding multiple series with different titles to your chart. Each series will have its own title and color.

```
// Each series represents one bar.
BarGraphSeries<DataPoint> series1 = new BarGraphSeries<DataPoint>(new DataPoint[]{ new DataPoint(1, personal)});
BarGraphSeries<DataPoint> series2 = new BarGraphSeries<DataPoint>(new DataPoint[]{ new DataPoint(2, fun)});
BarGraphSeries<DataPoint> series3 = new BarGraphSeries<DataPoint>(new DataPoint[]{ new DataPoint(3, work)});
BarGraphSeries<DataPoint> series4 = new BarGraphSeries<DataPoint>(new DataPoint[]{ new DataPoint(4, food)});
BarGraphSeries<DataPoint> series5 = new BarGraphSeries<DataPoint>(new DataPoint[]{ new DataPoint(5, commute)});
BarGraphSeries<DataPoint> series6 = new BarGraphSeries<DataPoint>(new DataPoint[]{ new DataPoint(6, bills)});

// Add titles to be displayed in the legend.
series1.setTitle("personal");
series2.setTitle("fun");
series3.setTitle("work");
series4.setTitle("food");
series5.setTitle("commute");
series6.setTitle("bills");

// Add color to your bars.
series1.setColor(Color.rbg(1,2,3));
series2.setColor(Color.rbg(4,5,6));
series3.setColor(Color.rbg(7,8,9));
series4.setColor(Color.rbg(0,1,2));
series5.setColor(Color.rbg(3,4,5));
series6.setColor(Color.rbg(6,7,8));

// Add each series to your graph.
graph.addSeries(series1);
graph.addSeries(series2);
graph.addSeries(series3);
graph.addSeries(series4);
graph.addSeries(series5);
graph.addSeries(series6);

// Display the legend.
graph.getLegendRenderer().setVisible(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use a custom legend renderer and extend the default implementation.
https://github.com/jjoe64/GraphView/blob/master/src/main/java/com/jjoe64/graphview/LegendRenderer.java

Or you disable the legend in graphview, use a FrameLayout and overlay the graph with your very own views for your legend